# Is it necessary to define entity file of the table if table already exists in typeorm(btw I am using postgres if it matters)?

Tags: postgresql, entity, typeorm, node.js-typeorm, typeorm-datamapper

If it is not necessary can anyone tell me the way? because I want to test a Typeorm query which actually has a lot of tables connected to it? defining all the tables will take a lot of time?

Comment: What's the issue you are struggling with? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can just simply define entities in typeorm for the tables that you actually need, switch SYNCHRONIZE to false and run your tests. Also, I would advise you to do this on the copy of the database.